# How this SQL Query Parse in SQLMS without an error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table Designation which has columns DesignationId, DesignationName. When I run this query on Sql Management studio Express

```
SELECT DesignationId DesignationName FROM Designation
```

instead of

```
SELECT DesignationId,DesignationName FROM Designation
```

It was parsed and return DesignationId alone as result.How it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first query , DesignationName is an alias for DesignationID, so if your table contains

```
DesignationID DesignationName
1             Bob
2             Fred
3             Kate
```

you will get

```
DesignationName
1
2
3
```

ie: it is equivalent to

```
SELECT DesignationId AS DesignationName FROM Designation
```